# Help combine IF formulas for list validation

Tags: validation-list-items

can someone help me? I want to combine two 5 lines of validation in a sharepoint list. I have been able to write a formula for one 1 line but not one that can combine all five validations.

Line 1
IF Column 1= ”document” then [column 2], [column 3], [column 4] cannot be blank
AND

Line 2
If [Column 5]=”notify’ then [column 5] cannot be blank

Line 3
If [Column 6] = “complete” then [Column 6] cannot be blank

Line 4
If [Column 4] = “No” then [Column 7] cannot be blank

Line 5
If [Column 10] = “Complete” then [Column 11] cannot be blank

I got line 1 to work with the following formula.

=IF([Column 1]="document",IF([column2]<>"",IF([column3]<>"",IF([column4]<>"",TRUE,FALSE))))

Can someone help me combine the 5 lines into one formula?

Comment: seems line 2 you have some type, you have mentioned column 5 in both sides

Answer (score 0):

For your conditions it would be like (with error for columns #5,6 conditions):

```
=IF(
    OR(
        AND(
            [Column 1]="document",
            OR([column2]="",[column3]="",[column4]="")
        ),
        AND(
            [Column 5]="notify",
            [column 5]=""
        ),
        AND(
            [Column 6]="complete",
            [Column 6]=""
        ),
        AND(
            [Column 4]="No",
            [Column 7]=""
        ),
        AND(
            [Column 10]="Complete",
            [Column 11]=""
        )
    ),
    false,true)
```